# The remote server returned an error 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, aspose

I am trying to move the mails from inbox to deleted folder. But when I run the program I am getting the above error message. Please help to solve this.
Here is my code

```
 string mailboxURI = "URL//"; 

        string username = "username";
        string password = "Password";
        string domain = "domain name";

        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Exchange Server....");
        try
        {
            NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
            ExchangeClient client = new ExchangeClient(mailboxURI, credential);

            ExchangeMailboxInfo mailboxInfo = client.GetMailboxInfo();

            // List all messages from Inbox folder
            Console.WriteLine("Listing all messages from Inbox....");
            ExchangeMessageInfoCollection msgInfoColl = client.ListMessages(mailboxInfo.InboxUri);
            foreach (ExchangeMessageInfo msgInfo in msgInfoColl)
            {
                // Move message to "Deleted" folder, after processing certain messages
                // based on some criteria
                if (msgInfo.Date != DateTime.Today)
                {
                    // Move it
                    client.MoveItems(msgInfo.UniqueUri, client.MailboxInfo.RootUri + "/Deleted/" + msgInfo.Subject);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message moved...." + msgInfo.Subject);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not moved:" + msgInfo.Subject);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:"+ex.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: something is wrong with ur url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes into picture when server is excepting method on server is not matching your http request type.

For eg. server is expecting http GET method however your code is using POST method to comunicate with server or viceversa.

You might want to change type of method in your code.

Cheers
Anant